# @Resource null at runtime but not at startup

Tags: java, jsp, jakarta-ee, servlets, ejb

I am new to Servlets and I tried to create a Helper class for Database access. I created this simple class and it works more or less. I can access the Database without any problems inside the "startUp" method, but when I access the methods inside the Servlets "dataSource" is always null. 
What am I doing wrong?

I am using Netbeans with Glassfish 4.1 and Java 7.

Database.class

```
@Singleton
@Startup
public class Database {

    @Resource( lookup = "jdbc/resBookStoreMySql" )
    private DataSource dataSource;

    @PostConstruct
    private void startUp() {
        System.err.println("=====================");
        System.err.println(this.dataSource == null); //false
    }

    @Lock( LockType.READ )
    public boolean isPasswordCorrect(String username, String password) {
        boolean isPasswordCorrect = false;
        System.err.println(this.dataSource == null); //true

        // . . . 

        return isPasswordCorrect;
    }

    @Lock(LockType.READ)
    public List<Book> getBooks() {
        List<Book> books = new ArrayList<>();
        System.err.println(this.dataSource == null); //true

        // . . . 

    return books;
    }
}
```

SomeServlet.jsp:

```
....
<jsp:useBean id="db" class="at.laubi.servlet.data.Database" scope="page" /> 
....
```

Comment: You have an EJB there. You should not inject your EJB directly in JSP but instead on your Servlet. Please avoid using `<jsp:useBean>` at all cost.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By using `useBean` you are instantiating new `Database` object, not injecting it and then `@Resource` is not processed and that's why dataSource is null.

As other suggested you shouldn't use EJB in jsp directly, but if you have to you need:

- add `@Named("database")` to you bean
- use for example `#{database.books}` in your JSP to get list of books